# ¿Porque cuando consigo el array de los datos de un canvas me devuelve el array del estado anterior del mismo?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Quiero hacer una web que obtenga el array de N imagenes mediante un canvas.

Tengo un pequeño formulario en que se puede agregar una etiqueta y tamaño, la etiqueta representa un directorio de destino y nombre de las imagenes, y el tamaño la cantidad que se repetirá el bucle.

Dependiendo de la cantidad de etiquetas que pongas se repiten las siguientes acciones:

- Conseguir el nombre y tamaño de la posición `i`.
- En la posición `j`, agregar a la imagen `imgData` la ruta de la imagen, la ruta que se envia es parecida a la siguiente `images/{nombre}/{nombre} ({j}).jpg`.
- Imprimir `imgData` a un `canvas` con un tamaño de `100x100`.
- Crear un arreglo que contendrá las filas y columnas del `canvas` y un string que convertirá el arreglo a cadena unida por `,`.
- Por `x` y por `y` conseguir los pixeles del `canvas`, agregarlos al array y luego converit el arreglo a cadena.
- Enviar la información al servidor (Este punto no lo tocaré mucho pues con esté no tengo problemas, básicamente conseguir todas la imagenes en cadena y en el servidor agregarlas a un array que luego convierto a archivo `scv`).

Es importante que exista una carpeta que contenga las carpetas para cada imagen, como `images/manzanas` y que cada imagen se llame como su directorio seguido de  `(N).jpg`, un ejemplo puede ser `images/manzanas/manzanas (1).jpg`.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente, cuando consigo el arreglo del canvas, me devuelve el arreglo del estado anterior del canvas, al iniciar me devuelve un arreglo en blanco, la siguiente vez que consigue los valores de la siguiente imagen me envia la primera que envie, y así sigue, nunca me devuelve la imagen actual, agregué una pequeña funcion para que al pasar el mouse se imprimieran en consola los pixeles, solo para ver si el canvas tenia bien la información, y si funciona, lo que me lleva a pensar que el orden o la forma en la que consigó los pixeles no es el adecuado, el código es el siguiente:

```js
let tag = 2,
  dataset = [];

function deleteTag(id) {
  $('#tag' + id).remove();
  tag--;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let imgSet = document.getElementById('imgData');

  function showImg(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
  }

  function pick(event) {
    var x = event.layerX;
    var y = event.layerY;
    var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
    var data = pixel.data;
    var color = 'COLOR(' + (data[2] / 255 * 100 / 100).toFixed(2) + ')';
    console.log(color);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
  $('#frmData').submit(async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataset = [];
    for (i = 1; i < tag; i++) {
      tagName = $(`#data_tag${i}`).val();
      tagSize = $(`#data_size${i}`).val();

      for (j = 1; j < parseInt(tagSize) + 1; j++) {
        showImg(`images/${tagName}/${tagName} (${j}).jpg`);

        let pixelesarr = [];
        let pixelesstring = '';
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
          for (y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            let imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1),
              pixels = imgData.data;
            valor = (pixels[2] / 255 * 100 / 100).toFixed(2);
            pixelesarr.push(valor);
          }
          pixelesstring = pixelesarr.join(',');
        }
        /*await $.post("http://localhost:8000", pixelesstring, respuesta => {
          console.log(respuesta);
        });*/
        await sleep(3000);
      }
    }
    console.log(dataset);
  });

  $('#btnAdd').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#frmData').append(`
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6" id="tag${tag}">
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="data_tag${tag}">
                Tag
            </label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="data_tag${tag}" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Tag" required>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="data_size${tag}">
                Size
            </label>
            <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="data_size${tag}" type="number" name="size" placeholder="Size" required>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
            <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="button" onclick="deleteTag(${tag})">
                Delete
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `);
    tag++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0-rc.3/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-tYLuvehjddL4JcVWw1wRMB0oPSz7fKEpdZrIWf3rWNA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg-stripes-white bg-stripes">
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 py-8">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <h1 class="ml-4 text-2xl font-bold">
          <span class="">Title</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 py-8">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold">
          <span class="">Generate</span>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mx-auto px-4 py-8">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <img src="" alt="Image" id="imgData" width="100" height="100">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100" class="border-2 border-blue-500"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form action="" method="" id="frmData">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="button" id="btnAdd">
                  Add a new tag
              </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit" id="btnGenerate">
                  Generate
              </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6" id="tag1">
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="data_tag1">
                  Tag
              </label>
        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="data_tag1" type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Tag" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="data_size1">
                  Size
              </label>
        <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="data_size1" type="number" name="size" placeholder="Size" required>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
        <button class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="button" onclick="deleteTag(0)">
                  Delete
              </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

> ***NOTA:*** El canvas y la imagen son solo para poder ver lo que hay en la imagen, para pruebas, lo cambiare por una barra de carga al final.

Cuando ejecuto todo, obtengo algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen que se envia es la que estaba antes en el canvas (imprimo la imagen desde el servidor con `matplotlib`), y como pueden ver la imagen se ve de costado, no se porque pasa eso, pero al ser un arreglo de `(100,100,1)` creo que no hay problema si en lugar de consegir los pixeles `ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1)` lo hago `ctx.getImageData(y,x,1,1)`.

En fin, ¿alguien sabe como debo conseguir los pixeles?

Answer (score 0):

Lo "Arregle", solamente puse otra espera de 500ms entre la funcion que dibuja la imagen y la que envia la imagen, porque me fijé de que primero se ejecutaba la petición y despues se ejecutaba la funcion de la imagen.

```js
for (j = 1; j < parseInt(tagSize)+1; j++) {
                        showImg(`images/${tagName}/${tagName} (${j}).jpg`);
                        //NUEVA ESPERA
                        await sleep(500);
                        let pixelesarr = [];
                        let pixelesstring = '';
                        for(x=0; x<100;x++){
                            for(y=0; y<100; y++){
                                let imgData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1),
                                    pixels = imgData.data;
                                    valor = (pixels[2]/255*100/100).toFixed(2);
                                pixelesarr.push(valor);
                            }
                            pixelesstring = pixelesarr.join(',');
                        }
                        await $.post("http://localhost:8000",pixelesstring,respuesta=>{
                            console.log(respuesta);
                        });
                        await sleep(3000);
                    }
                }
```

No creo que sea la opción mas optima, pero si alguien conoce una mejor opción por favor comentar

Comment: Realmente solo pusiste un "parche", pero no lo arreglaste, ¿qué pasa si la imagen tarda más en cargarse que el tiempo de espera?

Comment: Sí, eso estaba pensando, pero no se me ocurreo como solucionarlo, nada de lo que hago funciona

Comment: Creo que la opción sería generar las imágenes conforme se van agregando _tags_ y desactivar el botón hasta que se hayan cargado.

Comment: Creo que así lo dejaré, quería automatizar la creación de un dataset para tensorflow, pero lo hice manual al final, me tardé menos, pero lo terminaré cuando esté libre, igual gracias por comentar